# Android Marketplace icon

Tags: android, google-play

This is probably a dumb question but I can't find it anywhere... Which icon is used in your marketplace listing?  Is it always the application android:icon="@drawable/icon" setting from your manifest file or can you have a launch icon different from your marketplace listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an example will do:

```
// app-wide, incl. Android Market
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
// launcher only
    <activity android:name=".activity.Launcher"
        android:label="@string/launcher_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Android Market uses application icon, but you can have different launch icon if you assign another one to your default (starting) activity.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#icon
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#icon